# Permissions issue with vagrant virtualbox

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a Debian virtualbox set up with vagrant, in it i have the codebase for the project that i'm working on and i've set the folder which holds this codebase to be synced with the Host machine (which is Mac OS 10.8.4).  I just learned that in order to change the permissions on any subfolders on my synced folder i must do this from the host machine, however my problem is that the application actually creates folders (and subfolders) and then expects to be able to write to them.  Since the vm doesn't have the ability to chmod it's own folders these folders are not created with write access by default. How can this be achieved?

note: i've already tried using umask from both the host and the vm.  it works on the host but since those changes are per terminal they don't propagate to the vm, using it on the vm doesn't work because the folders are managed by the host.

Answer (score 0):

`umask` should be the way to go.

To make it persistent, you just need to add `umask 027` (or whatever mask you want) to `~/.bash_profile` for interactive login shell or `~/.bashrc` for interactive non-login shell for the user who will be running the application, or just make it system wide by placing in `/etc/profile`.

NOTE: Ubuntu uses `~/.profile` and does NOT have `~/.bash_profile`.

Alternatively, set umask before running the application would probably help.